# setting value in CFDictionary with Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

I'm just starting swift 3.0. I try to define a CFDictionary to set value.When the code run to function of "CFDictionarySetValue" , I got this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x7e8)

```
    var keyCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
    var valueCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks
    let query = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 4, &keyCallBacks,&valueCallBacks)

    var secClass = kSecClass
    var genericPassword = kSecClassGenericPassword
    CFDictionarySetValue(query,&secClass, &genericPassword)


    var attrCount = kSecAttrAccount
    var accountStr = "nothing_account" as CFString
    CFDictionarySetValue(query, &attrCount, &accountStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the cumbersome syntax to create `CF..` collection types, you could declare the dictionary as Swift `Dictionary` – you have to annotate it explicitly and bridge the keys to `String` – and bridge the dictionary to `CFDictionary` for example:

```
let query : [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String : kSecClassGenericPassword, 
                             kSecAttrAccount as String : "nothing_account"]

var result : CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)
```